# Rotating Gitlab's Service Account tokens with specified expiry

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, access-token, gitlab-api

I am currently using a Gitlab service account with its token and I want to set up a CICD job that automates the rotation of the service account tokens.

However from the [documenation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#rotate-a-personal-access-token-for-service-account-user), it seems there isn't a field where I can set the expiry date of the rotated tokens unlike the user's [personal access token rotation api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/personal_access_tokens.html#rotate-a-personal-access-token).

Trying it out and rotating service account tokens only gives it a `7` duration.

I would like to know if its possible to set an expiry for service account tokens' rotation.

If not, I would have to use Gitlab's scheduler to rotate the tokens every 6-7 days.
Another method i could think of its to revoke and create the service account tokens manually and set the job to run every `x` months. (this way, i could control the "expiry" per say)

Would  love to hear everyone's suggestions on this issue.